# Enable Java console log in browser

Tags: java, applet

I am supporting application that using Java applet.
How to get the console log in IE8 for this? I used to do it at older IE, by setting some option in Internet options and after that there is menu show Java Console , under View / Edit.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually enable the Java console permanently in the Java control panel advanced settings. While this must be done before starting the applet, it works in all browsers we have used so far.

Not a perfect answer but it might help.